# Quando usar o construtor de objeto de modelo baseado em Builder ao invés de passar parâmetros?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Quando se tem um `Builder` para criação de um objeto de modelo o método `build()` é responsável pela criação desse objeto, em muitos exemplos e materiais tenho visto essa criação feita de duas formas:

1. Utilizando o construtor da classe de modelo passando todos os valores para as propriedades como parâmetros separados.

```
public final class Cidade {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer codigo;
    private String descricao;

    private Cidade(final Integer codigo, final String descricao) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private Integer codigo;
        private String descricao;

        public static Builder create() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        public Builder codigo(final Integer codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder descricao(final String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
            return this;
        }

        public Cidade build() {
            return new Cidade(this.codigo, this.descricao);
        }

    }

}
```

2. Utilizando o construtor da classe de modelo passando o próprio `builder` como parâmetro e a partir dele são alimentadas as propriedades no construtor.

```
public final class Cidade {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer codigo;
    private String descricao;

    private Cidade(final Builder builder) {
        this.codigo = builder.codigo;
        this.descricao = builder.descricao;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private Integer codigo;
        private String descricao;

        public static Builder create() {
            return new Builder();
        }

        public Builder codigo(final Integer codigo) {
            this.codigo = codigo;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder descricao(final String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
            return this;
        }

        public Cidade build() {
            return new Cidade(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Para mim não está claro e gostaria de saber quando deve-se usar o construtor do objeto de modelo baseado em um Builder ao invés de passar parâmetros para o mesmo?

Comment: "Melhor" só faz sentido se houver parâmetros de comparação. Cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Mudei a abordagem da pergunta @Renan, "melhor" realmente não existe, minha intenção é gerar uma discussão sobre quando usar um ou outro tipo de abordagem, visto que isso ainda não está bem claro para mim.

Comment: Lucas, o SO não é direcionado a discussões. Existe inclusive um motivo para o fechamento de perguntas, chamado "Principalmente baseada em opiniões". Se você quer saber qual método deve utilizar, sugiro pesquisar sobre o propósito de cada um - aparentemente você está a estudar Padrões de Projeto (Design Patterns). Mas no final das contas, o melhor professor é a experiência - utilize ambos em exercícios pessoais e veja qual lhe traz mais benefícios em cada situação. Enquanto estiver fazendo isso, se tiver algum problema que está travando seu progresso, aí sim aqui é o lugar para se perguntar.

Comment: Ah, se você modificar o contexto da pergunta para "quando devo utilizar o padrão X"... ou melhor ainda, "por que o padrão X traz benefícios em relação ao padrão Y", acredito que as pessoas verão sua pergunta com melhores olhos por aqui.

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um construtor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/91)

Comment: Acho que a pergunta dele é válida. Tem como mostrar os "prós" e "contras" dessas abordagens sem entrar em detalhes de "baseado em opinião". Basta colocar vários exemplos e dizer com base na experiência qual foi a melhor opção que o desenvolvedor achou.

Comment: É a mesma coisa que perguntar sobre qual é a convenção correta para JS. A comunidade tem uma convenção, mas não tem um uma Nave Mãe como a MS que dita qual é a convenção do C#. No fim das contas, a convenção da comunidade é a convenção baseada em opiniões dominante, mas mesmo assim tem muita gente que responde essas questões aqui no SO e não negativa a pergunta.